# NFC Error code201- Timeout issue iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, nfc, ios11

Xcode 9.0, and iPhone 7 Plus iOS 11.0.3

I created AppId by selecting NFC Tag Reading.

I add to NFCReaderUsageDescription into info.plist such as below.

```
<key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key>
<string>NFC Tag!</string>
```

Then, Near Field Communication Tag Reading change to on at Capabilities.
Entitlements file already contain

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
<array>
    <string>NDEF</string>
</array>
```

I added to NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate to use ReaderSession Delegates.

In the ViewDidLoad,

```
NFCNDEFReaderSession *session = [[NFCNDEFReaderSession alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT) invalidateAfterFirstRead:NO];
[session beginSession];
```

Always, didInvalidateWithError is working such as Error Domain=NFCError Code=201 "Session is invalidated due to maximum session timeout".

How to fix this problem?